For Prime Monic Polynomial $P$ Over $\mathbb{F}_5$: There's a Solution to $y^2 \equiv x \pmod{P}$ if and only if $P(0)$ Is a Square Modulo 5
I need to show that if $P$ is a prime and monic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_5$, such that $P(x) \neq x$, then there is a solution to $y^2 \equiv x \pmod{P}$ if and only if $P(0)$ is a square modulo 5. I'm struggling with the first direction ($\Rightarrow$):
I know that if there is a solution to $y^2 \equiv x \pmod{P}$, then the Legendre symbol of $x$ over $P$ with $d = 2$ is equal to 1 — i.e.,
$$
x^{(|P|-1)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{P}.
$$
Therefore, there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$ such that:
$$
Q(x) \cdot P(x) = x^{(|P|-1)/2} - 1.
$$
I would like to show that $P(0)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, and then, by a theorem from Number Theory, I'll get that there exists a solution to $t^2 \equiv P(0) \pmod{5}$, i.e., $P(0)$ is a square modulo 5 — but I can't find a sufficient reason for $P(0)$ to be $1 \pmod{5}$ or $4 \pmod{5}$.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Let $P(x)$ be monic irreducible degree $d$ over a field $K$. Let $L = K[x]/P(x)$. Given $y^2=x\bmod P(x)$, let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the images of $x,y$ respectively in $L$. The point is that the norm of $\alpha$ is $(-1)^d\cdot P(0)$. The norm of $\alpha$ is the square of the norm of $\beta$, thus
$$(-1)^d \cdot P(0)=N(\alpha)=N(\beta)^2=\gamma^2, \quad \gamma \in K.$$
With $K = \mathbf{F}_5$ you find that $\pm P(0)$ is square, and so  $0,\pm 1\bmod 5$. Conversely if $K=\mathbf{F}_q$; if $N(\alpha)=(-1)^d P(0)$ is square, so is $\alpha$ since $N$ is surjective and $L^{\times}$ is cyclic.

Does $\lvert P\rvert$ mean the size of the splitting field of $P$?
